# Promise in angular.js + node.js/electron doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron

I'm using angular.js in electron along with node-orm to talk to a database. Node-orm find/get functions are async so I tried to use Promises to get data in a service like so:

```
app.service('SearchService', function($q) {
  this.title = function(token) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Unit.find({}).where("unit_title LIKE ?", ['%'+token.toUpperCase()+'%']).run(function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('error running title query', err);}
      deferred.resolve(results);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
app.controller("GreetController", function($scope, SearchService) {
  $scope.units = SearchService.title('test');
});
```

With the goal of angular translating the promise in the view itself.:

```
<div ng-controller="GreetController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="unit in units">{{unit.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

However it doesn't work. I know the Promises resolve since I can log them to the console and view the values with Chromium's dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are still asynchronous operations, so `title` method returns a promise object, not actual `results`. You need to use promise then-able API to provide callbacks that will be called when data is available:

```
app.controller("GreetController", function($scope, SearchService) {
  SearchService.title('test').then(function(data) {
      $scope.units = data;
  });
});
```